# A fast algorithm for maximum normalized subarray sum?

Tags: algorithm

The maximum subarray sum problem has a very simple linear time solution https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem.

If instead we want to maximize sum(subarray)/sqrt(subarray length), is there a subquadratic time solution?

The elements of the input array will be floating point values in the range -infinity to +infinity.

Comment: My gut feeling says that you essentially make it a multidimensional problem. One dimension for arrays of length 1, one dimension for arrays of length 2, etc. I don't have concrete proof of that though.

Comment: Is that floor or regular division?

Comment: Regular division

Comment: @maraca Can you say more about why it would work for integer valued arrays?

Comment: @Anush sorry I take it back. I thought the square root has too little effect, but if the numbers are big it is wrong.

Comment: If you can come up with a subquadratic way to find the maximum normalised subarray sum *that crosses a given position i*, then you could solve your problem in subquadratic time with divide and conquer (solve the constrained subproblem with i = n/2, then recurse to solve the left and right halves of the original problem).  I can think of heuristics that probably work well in typical cases, but nothing with a subquadratic guarantee.

Comment: So a solution in `O(n^2)` isn't ok?

Comment: @Yonlif Right. I am looking for something better than that.

Comment: Would approximation rather than optimal be helpful?

Comment: @גלעדברקן An approximate answer would be interesting too, especially if a fast optimal solution proves impossible.

Comment: I have an idea, how to modify Kadane algorithm, but because function is not linear we cannot keep only one maximum and worst case scenario will still be O(N^2). But average case can be close to O(N). Imagine that you have some best subarray cases with different length. If you know length of whole array you know how small best sum can be if it will take all the array, so it's kind of worst case drop scenario. In this case you can drop some items just because their best state is worse than worst state of another items. This will allow you to iterate to next i+1 set and track less.

Comment: One easy trick that might help if you have many negative numbers: An optimal interval can *span* negative entries, but it can never *end* at one (since you could always chop it off to get a higher-weight interval).  So you can combine all runs of adjacent negative entries into a single entry having weight equal to their sum.  A slightly more complicated version handles more cases: if you have a run of k positive entries with sum x in between 2 negative entries, both < -x, then either the optimal solution is inside the run, or it spans all k+2 entries (which can be summed into a single entry).

Comment: Note that the above is true only if there is at least one nonnegative entry.  If all entries are negative, the optimal solution is a single-entry interval containing just the largest (closest to zero) entry.  (Proof sketch: Starting from any given interval, pretend that every entry in it is equal to the largest entry in it, x, in order to get an upper bound of x\*y/sqrt(y) on the interval's weight, where y is the interval length.  y/sqrt(y) = sqrt(y) is a strictly increasing function of y, so the smaller we make y, the less negative x\*y/sqrt(y) becomes, finally equalling its UB at y=1.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks. We can expect there to be both positive and negative entries.

Comment: I added a version of estabroo's Kadane-based code to the testing in my answer. It seems to show a difference of up to 10% or so from brute-force.

Answer (score 5):

#### UPDATE

I added a version of estabroo's Kadane-based code to the testing below. It seems to show a difference of up to 10% in my testing (run the snippet for random tests).

(End update)

The best I could come up with so far as an approximation is a binary search on the target with random samples of window-size during the search `O(log m * n * num_samples_constant)`, where `m` is the range. In testing I saw the variation between brute-force (limited to 5000 element array, ranged ±1000000000) and the latter vary between 0 and 30% with a sample size of 200 window-lengths. (Maybe another routine could further refine?)

The JavaScript code below runs 10 tests and reports smallest and largest diffs, followed by just the binary search on a longer array.

Other thoughts included using FFT to generate the sums but I don't know if there could be an efficient way to then correlate each sum with the subarray-length that generated it; as well as trying to find another representation of the problem:

```
f = sqrt(i - j) * (si - sj), for j < i
f^2 = sqrt(i - j) * (si - sj) * sqrt(i - j) * (si - sj)
    = (i - j) * (si^2 - 2si*sj + sj^2)
    = i*si^2 - 2i*si*sj + i*sj^2
      -j*si^2 + 2j*si*sj - j*sj^2

    = i*si^2 + 
      (-2sj, sj^2, -j, 2j*sj, -j*sj^2) // known before i
        dot (i*si, 1, si^2, si, 1)
```

(So if we solved a 5-dimensional convex hull update in log time, the 5-dimensional extreme point problem, and figured out if our candidate was positive or negative, we'd be good to go :)

```js
function prefix_sums(A){
  let ps = new Array(A.length + 1).fill(0)
  for (let i=0; i<A.length; i++)
    ps[i + 1] = A[i] + ps[i]
  return ps
}

function brute_force(ps){
  let best = -Infinity
  let best_idxs = [-1, -1]
  for (let i=1; i<ps.length; i++){
    for (let j=0; j<i; j++){
      let s = (ps[i] - ps[j]) / Math.sqrt(i - j)
      if (s > best){
        best = s
        best_idxs = [j, i - 1]
      }
    }
  }
  return [best, best_idxs]
}

function get_high(A){
  return A.reduce((acc, x) => x > 0 ? acc + x : acc, 0)
}

function get_low(A){
  return Math.min.apply(null, A)
}


function f(A){
  let n = A.length
  let ps = prefix_sums(A)
  let high = get_high(A)
  let low = get_low(A)
  let best = [-1, -1]
  let T = low + (high - low) / 2
  let found = false

  while (low + EPSILON < high){
    T = low + (high - low) / 2
    // Search for T
    found = false

    for (let l=0; l<NUM_SAMPLES; l++){
      let w = Math.max(1, ~~(Math.random() * (n + 1)))

      for (let i=w; i<ps.length; i++){
        let s = (ps[i] - ps[i - w]) / Math.sqrt(w)
        if (s >= T){
          found = true
          best = [i - w, i - 1]
          break
        }
      }
      if (found)
        break
    }
    // Binary search
    if (found)
      low = T
    else
      high = T - EPSILON 
  }

  return [low, best]
}

function max_subarray(A){
    var max_so_far = max_ending_here = A[0]
    var startOld = start = end = 0
    var divb = divbo = 1
    //for i, x in enumerate(A[1:], 1):
    for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++){
        var x = A[i]
        divb = i - start + 1
        divbo = divb - 1
        if (divb <= 1){
            divb = 1
            divbo = 1
        }
        undo = max_ending_here * Math.sqrt(divbo)
        max_ending_here = Math.max(x, (undo + x)/Math.sqrt(divb))
        if (max_ending_here == x)
            start = i
        max_so_far = Math.max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
        if (max_ending_here < 0)
            start = i + 1
        else if (max_ending_here == max_so_far){
            startOld = start
            end = i
        }
    }
    if (end == A.length-1){
        start = startOld + 1
        var new_max = max_so_far
        divbo = end - startOld + 1
        divb = divbo - 1
        while (start < end){
            new_max = (new_max * Math.sqrt(divbo) - A[start-1])/Math.sqrt(divb)
            if (new_max > max_so_far){
                max_so_far = new_max
                startOld = start
            }
            start += 1
        }
    }
    return [max_so_far , startOld, end]
}

const EPSILON = 1
const NUM_SAMPLES = 200

let m = 1000000000
let n = 5000
let A

let max_diff = 0
let min_diff = Infinity
let max_diff2 = 0
let min_diff2 = Infinity
let num_tests = 10

for (let i=0; i<num_tests; i++){
  A = []
  for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
    A.push([-1, 1][~~(2 * Math.random())] * Math.random() * m + Math.random())

  let f_A = f(A)
  let g_A = brute_force(prefix_sums(A))
  let m_A = max_subarray(A)
  let diff = (g_A[0] - f_A[0]) / g_A[0]
  max_diff = Math.max(max_diff, diff)
  min_diff = Math.min(min_diff, diff)
  let diff2 = (g_A[0] - m_A[0]) / g_A[0]
  max_diff2 = Math.max(max_diff2, diff2)
  min_diff2 = Math.min(min_diff2, diff2)
}

console.log(`${ n } element array`)
console.log(`${ num_tests } tests`)
console.log(`min_diff: ${ min_diff * 100 }%`)
console.log(`max_diff: ${ max_diff * 100 }%`)
console.log(`min_diff (Kadane): ${ min_diff2 * 100 }%`)
console.log(`max_diff (Kadane): ${ max_diff2 * 100 }%`)

n = 100000
A = []
for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
  A.push([-1, 1][~~(2 * Math.random())] * Math.random() * m + Math.random())

var start = +new Date()
console.log(`\n${ n } element array`)
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A)))
console.log(`${ (new Date() - start) / 1000 } seconds`)
```

Comment: How accurate/fast is the Kadane based solution?  Is anything provable?

Comment: @Anush I would ask David Eisenstat that :) It depends on your data - I'd imagine we could come up with data that performs better or worse. If your data is more-or-less random, you could test this by running some robust comparisons of estabroo's code with brute-force on random data and check if it would fit your needs. (By robust, I mean many tests with many different sized lists and element ranges.)

Comment: @Anush David Eisenstat seemed to offer a provable approximation scheme. Why not try to implement and test that?

Comment: @Anush The Kadane modification is linear-time but loses the optimal substructure of the original. It does especially poorly on arrays like [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...] because it keeps truncating the best-up-to-here sequence based on local considerations, achieving objective value 1, but the best solution is to take the whole array or close to it, achieving objective value Theta(sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem. Since you mentioned an interest in approximations, here's a 1−O(ε) approximation scheme that runs in O(nε<sup>−1</sup>) time. It has the nice property of using only + and max, sidestepping the problem of catastrophic cancellation brought on by subtracting prefix sums. (Since the input contains negative numbers, it's still possible to get catastrophic cancellation, but then we could settle for the subarray containing only the large positive integer involved.)

Let k = ceil(ε<sup>−1</sup>). In O(nε<sup>−1</sup>) time we can evaluate every subarray of length between 1 and k using a straightforward algorithm. We evaluate longer subarrays in an approximate manner by iteratively coarsening the input and running basically the same algorithm. Since the input shrinks by a constant factor in each iteration, the total running time is O(nε<sup>−1</sup>).

The coarsening procedure works as follows. We keep three derived arrays of the same length. Each position in the derived arrays corresponds to a subarray of length 2<sup>ℓ</sup> in the original input. The three derived arrays are S (each element is the maximum sum of a suffix of the corresponding subarray), A (each element is the sum of the corresponding subarray), and P (each element is maximum sum of a prefix of the corresponding subarray). Considering S[i] + A[i+1] + … + A[j−1] + P[j] for some i < j, we have the maximum sum of a subarray of the input that starts in the subarray corresponding to position i and ends in the subarray corresponding to position j. The length of the subarray attaining this sum is between 2<sup>ℓ</sup> (j−i−1) + 2 and 2<sup>ℓ</sup> (j−i+1). This suffices to bound the objective (if the sum is positive, use the latter as the estimate for the number of elements; if the sum is negative, use the former) and can thus can approximately compare it to other subarrays.

To derive S′, A′, P′ from S, A, P in each iteration, we compute S′[i] = max(S[2i]+A[2i+1], S[2i+1]) and A′[i] = A[2i] + A[2i+1] and P′[i] = max(P[2i], A[2i] + P[2i+1]). If index 2i exists but 2i+1 does not, we set S′[2i] = S[2i] and A′[2i] = A[2i] and P′[2i] = P[2i].

The proof sketch of 1−O(ε) approximation is that, given the optimal subarray, we find the least ℓ such that its length is at most 2<sup>ℓ−1</sup>k. Then we look at iteration ℓ, find the i and j, observe that S[i] + A[i+1] + … + A[j−1] + P[j] is at least as large as the sum of the optimal subarray, and bound the loss incurred by rounding up the denominator by a multiplicative factor of 1+O(ε).

Comment: I like the idea of estimating the number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

The Kadane algorithm (2nd one shows tracking start and end of subarray) shown in that wikipedia page should work for this as well since (a + b)/sqrt(n) is the same as a/sqrt(n) + b/sqrt(n).  So instead of adding the full value (max_end_here + x) you'd undo the previous division, add the new value and then divide by the square root of the new length.

```
import math
def max_subarray(A):
    max_so_far = max_ending_here = A[0]
    startOld = start = end = 0
    divb = divbo = 1
    for i, x in enumerate(A[1:], 1):
        divb = i - start + 1
        divbo = divb - 1
        if divb <= 1:
            divb = 1
            divbo = 1
        undo = max_ending_here * math.sqrt(divbo)
        max_ending_here = max(x, (undo + x)/math.sqrt(divb))
        if max_ending_here == x: # reset when a single number is larger than previous max subarray
            start = i
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
        if max_ending_here < 0:
            start = i + 1
        elif max_ending_here == max_so_far:
            startOld = start
            end = i
    # check if shortening increases max
    start = startOld + 1
    new_max = max_so_far
    divbo = end - startOld + 1
    divb = divbo - 1
    while (start < end):
        new_max = (new_max * math.sqrt(divbo) - A[start-1])/math.sqrt(divb)
        if new_max > max_so_far:
            max_so_far = new_max
            startOld = start
        start += 1
        divb -= 1
        divbo -= 1
        if divb < 1:
            break
    return (max_so_far , startOld, end)

a = [-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]
print(a)
print(max_subarray(a))
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]
print(a)
print(max_subarray(a))

a = [-571218039.35953,993870065.9750855,520554093.5890911,336453508.124072,341730314.3580449]
print(a)
print(max_subarray(a))

a = [993870065.9750855,-571218039.35953,520554093.5890911,336453508.124072,341730314.3580449]
print(a)
print(max_subarray(a))

a = [903293995.5092816, -446822629.61604935, -441981815.2268512, 918327233.3661327, -172699078.33198473]
print(a)
print(max_subarray(a))

a = [-627703132.0023746,-269316542.4622296,267057965.81026044,568764120.4442698,767020098.5785978]
print(a)
print(max_subarray(a))
```

[image]

Comment: yep, it was incorrect, fixed it to not miss first element in list.  It probably has some other issues but I believe the general idea is sound and using Kadane's algorithm will work for this problem.

Comment: python3 is what I'm running it with. Maybe 3rd times the charm, divbo wasn't being reset with divb, added two more tests as well.

Comment: You are really good at finding corner cases.  This one was end shortening.  Once it hit end of list it wasn't shortening the subarray to see if something was larger.  Added a loop to check that.

Comment: @גלעד ברקן very nice (already see that I mucked up the end shortening with that) :)

Comment: I added a version of your code to the testing in my answer. It seems to show a difference of up to 10% or so from brute-force (significantly better than my current configuration for the binary search).

Comment: I can't tell how good the approximation is that you get from your algorithm. Do you have a feeling for this? Is anything provable?

Comment: out of curiosity I ran that brute vs it 10k times (arrays of 100 random floats), 88% of the time it got the correct answer and on a miss it's guess it averaged within 96% of the correct answer. I don't have anything provable, but I'd guess arrays with strong peaks it finds the correct one but gets a smoothed out answer on arrays with weaker peaks.

Comment: added a plot of a miss, it found an answer that was close to the real answer, but pulled from a different range.  The algo isn't resetting it's subarray selection properly.  I also tried it with larger arrays, the correct percentage dropped to about 74% at 2000 items in the array but the misses still stayed close to the real value.  The variance on the miss tightened a bit and increased to ~97%